# 'RoutePrefixAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute' and 'System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefixAttribute'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My MVC WebAPI project has been working fine, but suddenly it doesn't compile and I am getting the following error.  I am using Attribute routing.  I need both the assemblies reference.  I've tried

\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0  and 
\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.2

Does anyone know how to fix this?

'RoutePrefixAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute' and 'System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefixAttribute'

'RouteAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute' 
and 'System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute'

Answer (score 2):

Use full name  `[System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("smt")]`or make alias for reference

```
using a =System.Web.Http;
using b = System.Web.Mvc;

[a.RoutePrefix("smt")]
```

Comment: Thank you.  After uninstall and reinstall both assemblies several times, it finally resolved the ambiguity.